# How can I conditionally render raw HTML with v-html inside a nested v-for loop in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to conditionally render a chunk of HTML inside a nested v-for loop.

In the nested v-for I'm already binding a class to each element, that satisfies a certain condition.

So the class `'fret-mark-1'` is added to the div if `stringNumber === 0` (the first rendered element in the parent v-for loop) and the fret-number is found in the `fretMark1` array: `fretMark1.indexOf(fret) >= 0`

```
<div class="fretboard">
    <div v-for="(string, stringNumber) in numberOfStrings" class="string" v-bind:class="'string' + stringNumber">
      <div v-for="fret in numberOfFrets" class="note" v-bind:class="{ 'fret-mark-1': stringNumber === 0 && fretMark1.indexOf(fret) >= 0 ? true : false}" v-bind:data-note="generateNoteString(instrumentTuningPresets[selectedInstrument][stringNumber] + (fret - 1), showFlats)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That works great, but when I want to add a div inside a nested element based on another condition it becomes a problem.

I have another array stored on the Vue instance called `fretMark2`, and I want to add `<div class="fret-mark-2"></div>` to the elements where `stringNumber === 0` and `fretMark2.indexOf(fret) >= 0`

Something like this, if it was possible:

```
<div v-if="stringNumber === 0 && fretMark2.indexOf(fret) >= 0 ? true : false">{{ <div class="fret-mark-2"></div> }}</div>
```

But of course in Vue2 we can't render raw HTML with interpolation - we have to use v-html. I just can't figure out how to use v-html based on a condition inside a v-for loop.

[Here is a link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vellebelle/gq75a7ra/26/)

I hope someone can help.

Comment: why not use a custom directive? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Intro

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `v-html="some_method(html)"`, then write a method (in my example, `some_method`) that contains the conditions for rendering the html.

Comment: `<div v-if="stringNumber === 0 && fretMark2.indexOf(fret) >= 0 ? true : false" v-html=\`<div class="fret-mark-2"></div>\`></div>`

Comment: Aaaah, of course.. Thank you @JacobGoh That makes a lot of sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something like this, if it was possible:
>
> ```
> <div v-if="stringNumber === 0 && fretMark2.indexOf(fret) >= 0 ? true : false">{{ <div class="fret-mark-2"></div> }}</div>
> ```
>
> But of course in Vue2 we can't render raw HTML with interpolation - we have to use v-html.

You don't actually need to use string interpolation or `v-html` for this. You can simply add `v-if` to the conditional `<div>`:

```
<div v-for="fret in numberOfFrets" ...>
  <div v-if="stringNumber === 0 && fretMark2.indexOf(fret) >= 0"
       class="fret-mark-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, `div.fret-mark-2` would only be added to the DOM if the `v-if` condition evaluates to `true`.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9hkdg98/2/)

Comment: Thank you @tony19. That works! Simpler than I expected.

Comment: @MortenVestergaard No problem :)